# Cannot uninstall TrueCrypt

Tags: apt, uninstall, encryption

I installed TrueCrypt from their website (.tar.gz file) extracted through the archive manager to `/usr/share/truecrypt`. I no longer need the app but I cannot uninstall it through

```
sudo apt-get remove
```

I get an error message:

```
'virtual packages like truecrypt cannot be removed'.
```

All of the sub-directories and files in `/usr/share/truecrypt` have a padlock symbol on them.

I don't know how to remove unwanted apps beyond these basics, I'm hoping you can help. I have a small(memory),  elderly Toshiba Satelite laptop so it doesn't need to carry any baggage.

Thanks, 
David

[image]

Answer (score 6):

[image]

Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo /.'/usr/bin/truecrypt-uninstall.sh'
```

which returns the output:

```
TrueCrypt uninstalled.
```

This is the normal way to uninstall TrueCrypt, but you said you extracted the TrueCrypt files to `/usr/share/truecrypt` which isn't the normal way of installing TrueCrypt, so if the above commands don't work, open the terminal and run the following commands:

```
cd /usr/share/  # change directories to the directory that contains truecrypt
sudo rm -r truecrypt  # remove the truecrypt directory and all of its contents
```