# How to uninstall program, which was installed via ./

Tags: uninstall

I'm using 14.04 LTS.
Installed programm is truecrypt-6.3a-setup-ubuntu-x86
I installed via following command

```
sudo ./truecrypt-6.3a-setup-ubuntu-x86
```

Ubuntu software center doesn't show me installed truecrypt
None of

```
sudo apt-get remove truecrypt
sudo dkpg --remove truecrypt
```

works.
It shows me that truecrypt doesn't installed.

```
apt-cache pkgnames | grep true
```

returns none of either truecrypt or something similar
Well, it probably should go, but I cannot find /usr/bin/truecrypt-uninstall.sh as well as usr/share/truecrypt-uninstall.sh
searchmonkey returns zero of truecrypt except truecrypt.mod and downloaded files
What can I do?

Comment: run `sudo ./truecrypt-6.3a-setup-ubuntu-x86 --help` or `sudo ./truecrypt-6.3a-setup-ubuntu-x86 --uninstall`

Comment: @Panther doesn't work. Command opens installer, as it was without --uninstall key and there are only three options: exit, extract deb package file, install Truecrypt

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/463785/cannot-uninstall-truecrypt

Comment: Well, it probably should go, but I cannot find /usr/bin/truecrypt-uninstall.sh as well as usr/share/truecrypt-uninstall.sh searchmonkey returns zero of truecrypt except truecrypt.mod and downloaded files

Comment: Take the time to read the first answer "This is the normal way to uninstall TrueCrypt, but you said you extracted the TrueCrypt files to /usr/share/truecrypt which isn't the normal way of installing TrueCrypt, so if the above commands don't work, open the terminal and run the following commands:" it goes on how to remove if you can not find the uninstall script depending on how you installed. So for that reason, and not the lack of an uninstall script, your question was marked as a duplicate. If that fails, update the question with the additional information and it would likely be reopened.

Comment: @karel  
To be honest, I didn't delete Truecrypt 6.3. Tried several ways, but had no luck. But because I need TrueCrypt (but latest version) I installed over 6.3 latest version 7.1a and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the terminal and type:

```
which truecrypt
```

The results will be something like:

```
/usr/bin/truecrypt
```

If you see the above results run the following commands to uninstall TrueCrypt manually:

```
sudo -i
rm -f /usr/bin/truecrypt
rm -f /usr/share/truecrypt/doc/License.txt
rm -f '/usr/share/truecrypt/doc/TrueCrypt User Guide.pdf'
rm -f /usr/share/applications/truecrypt.desktop
rm -f /usr/share/pixmaps/truecrypt.xpm
rm -rf /usr/share/truecrypt/doc /usr/share/truecrypt
rm -f /usr/bin/truecrypt-uninstall.sh
```

Comment: To be honest, I didn't delete Truecrypt 6.3. Just installed over 6.3 latest version 7.1a